# Why won't this xml file with MobileFormFactor for office addin work

Tags: manifest, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to follow a couple examples online to add a mobile task pane to my office add-in app but seem to be stuck at this error now. What is going wrong. "installation failed: versionoverrides 1.0 secon of the manifest is invalid. The MobileFormFactor tag is invalid"

[image]

my guide that I'm using to pattern this is https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo/blob/master/command-demo-manifest.xml

If i remove the inner VersionOverrides tag this will install fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MailApp">
   <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->
   <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
   <Id>some-id</Id>
   <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
   <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
   <ProviderName>Red Planet</ProviderName>
   <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
   <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
   <DisplayName DefaultValue="Red Planet special" />
   <Description DefaultValue="Red Planet Outlook special Support" />
   <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
   <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://somedomain/assets/icon.png" />
   <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://somedomain/assets/icon.png" />
   <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
   <!-- <SupportUrl DefaultValue="[Insert the URL of a page that provides support information for the app]" /> -->
   <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
   <AppDomains>
      <AppDomain>https://somedomain</AppDomain>
      <AppDomain>https://somedomain</AppDomain>
      <!-- <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain> -->
   </AppDomains>
   <!--End Basic Settings. -->
   <Hosts>
      <Host Name="Mailbox" />
   </Hosts>
   <Requirements>
      <Sets>
         <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
      </Sets>
   </Requirements>
   <FormSettings>
      <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
         <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://somedomain/index.html" />
            <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
         </DesktopSettings>
      </Form>
   </FormSettings>
   <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
   <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="ReadOrEdit" />
   </Rule>
   <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
   <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
      <Requirements>
         <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
            <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
         </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
         <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
               <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
               <FunctionFile resid="fnFile" />
               <!-- Message Read -->
               <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                  <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
                  <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                     <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                     <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                        <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                        <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                           <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                           <Supertip>
                              <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                              <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                           </Supertip>
                           <Icon>
                              <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                              <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                           </Icon>
                           <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                              <FunctionName>showspecialModal</FunctionName>
                           </Action>
                        </Control>
                     </Group>
                  </OfficeTab>
               </ExtensionPoint>
               <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                  <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
                  <OfficeTab id="TabDefault2">
                     <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                     <Group id="msgReadGroup2">
                        <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                        <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton2">
                           <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                           <Supertip>
                              <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                              <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                           </Supertip>
                           <Icon>
                              <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                              <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                           </Icon>
                           <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                              <FunctionName>showspecialModal</FunctionName>
                           </Action>
                        </Control>
                     </Group>
                  </OfficeTab>
               </ExtensionPoint>
               <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
            </DesktopFormFactor>
         </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
         <bt:Images>
            <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://somedomain/assets/icon.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://somedomain/assets/icon.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://somedomain/assets/icon.png" />
         </bt:Images>
         <bt:Urls>
            <bt:Url id="fnFile" DefaultValue="https://somedomain/#functions" />
            <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://somedomain/#task-pane" />
         </bt:Urls>
         <bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Red Planet" />
            <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="Red Planet Tab" />
            <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="special Reply" />
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties" />
            <bt:String id="groupLabel2" DefaultValue="Red Planet2" />
            <bt:String id="customTabLabel2" DefaultValue="Red Planet Tab2" />
            <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel2" DefaultValue="special Reply2" />
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle2" DefaultValue="Get all properties2" />
         </bt:ShortStrings>
         <bt:LongStrings>
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Open up the special send dialog." />
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription2" DefaultValue="Open up the special send dialog." />
         </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
      <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
         <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
               <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
            </bt:Sets>
         </Requirements>
         <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
               <MobileFormFactor>
                  <FunctionFile resid="fnFile" />
                  <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
                     <Group id="mobileGroupID">
                        <Label resid="residAppName" />
                        <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="TaskPaneBtn">
                           <Label resid="residTaskPaneButtonName" />
                           <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                              <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="icon16" />
                           </Icon>
                           <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                              <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                           </Action>
                        </Control>
                     </Group>
                  </ExtensionPoint>
               </MobileFormFactor>
            </Host>
         </Hosts>
         <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
               <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://somedomain/assets/icon.png" />
               <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://somedomain/assets/icon.png" />
               <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://somedomain/assets/icon.png" />
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
               <bt:Url id="fnFile" DefaultValue="https://somedomain/#functions" />
               <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://somedomain/#task-pane" />
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
               <bt:String id="residTaskPaneButtonName" DefaultValue="Mobile test" />
               <bt:String id="residAppName" DefaultValue="Mobile Testing" />
               <bt:String id="residTaskpaneUrl" DefaultValue="Mobile test2" />
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
               <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Open up the special send dialog." />
               <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription2" DefaultValue="Open up the special send dialog." />
            </bt:LongStrings>
         </Resources>
      </VersionOverrides>
   </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in the manifest you have posted ...

- `DefaultMinVersion` of the `VersionOverridesV1_0` (1.5) section cannot be higher than specified in the `VersionOverridesV1_1` (1.3).
- The `Url` resource should lead to `.html` file, including `FunctionFile`.
- `VersionOverridesV1_1` section doesn't take anything from `VersionOverridesV1_0` section and you have to repeat `ExtensionPoint` and appropriate `Resources` inside `VersionOverridesV1_1`.

When you fix all of the point above the manifest should looks like the following XML and will work ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MailApp">
   <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->
   <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
   <Id>your_id</Id>
   <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
   <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
   <ProviderName>Red Planet</ProviderName>
   <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
   <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
   <DisplayName DefaultValue="Red Planet special" />
   <Description DefaultValue="Red Planet Outlook special Support" />
   <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
   <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/app-32.png" />
   <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/app-80.png" />
   <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
   <!-- <SupportUrl DefaultValue="[Insert the URL of a page that provides support information for the app]" /> -->
   <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
   <AppDomains>
      <AppDomain>https://somedomain.com</AppDomain>
      <AppDomain>https://somedomain.com</AppDomain>
      <!-- <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain> -->
   </AppDomains>
   <!--End Basic Settings. -->
   <Hosts>
      <Host Name="Mailbox" />
   </Hosts>
   <Requirements>
      <Sets>
         <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
      </Sets>
   </Requirements>
   <FormSettings>
      <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
         <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/index.html" />
            <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
         </DesktopSettings>
      </Form>
   </FormSettings>
   <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
   <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="ReadOrEdit" />
   </Rule>
   <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
   <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
      <Requirements>
         <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
            <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
         </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
         <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
               <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
               <FunctionFile resid="fnFile" />
               <!-- Message Read -->
               <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                  <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
                  <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                     <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                     <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                        <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                        <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                           <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                           <Supertip>
                              <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                              <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                           </Supertip>
                           <Icon>
                              <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                              <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                           </Icon>
                           <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                              <FunctionName>showspecialModal</FunctionName>
                           </Action>
                        </Control>
                     </Group>
                  </OfficeTab>
               </ExtensionPoint>
               <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                  <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
                  <OfficeTab id="TabDefault2">
                     <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                     <Group id="msgReadGroup2">
                        <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                        <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton2">
                           <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                           <Supertip>
                              <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                              <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                           </Supertip>
                           <Icon>
                              <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                              <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                           </Icon>
                           <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                              <FunctionName>showspecialModal</FunctionName>
                           </Action>
                        </Control>
                     </Group>
                  </OfficeTab>
               </ExtensionPoint>
               <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
            </DesktopFormFactor>
         </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
         <bt:Images>
            <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/app-16.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/app-32.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/app-80.png" />
         </bt:Images>
         <bt:Urls>
            <bt:Url id="fnFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/functions.html" />
            <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/task-pane.html" />
         </bt:Urls>
         <bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Red Planet" />
            <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="Red Planet Tab" />
            <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="special Reply" />
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties" />
            <bt:String id="groupLabel2" DefaultValue="Red Planet2" />
            <bt:String id="customTabLabel2" DefaultValue="Red Planet Tab2" />
            <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel2" DefaultValue="special Reply2" />
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle2" DefaultValue="Get all properties2" />
         </bt:ShortStrings>
         <bt:LongStrings>
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Open up the special send dialog." />
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription2" DefaultValue="Open up the special send dialog." />
         </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
      <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
         <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
               <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
            </bt:Sets>
         </Requirements>
         <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
              <DesktopFormFactor>
                 <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
                 <FunctionFile resid="fnFile" />
                 <!-- Message Read -->
                 <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                    <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                       <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                       <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                          <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                          <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                          <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                             <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                             <Supertip>
                                <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                                <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                             </Supertip>
                             <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                             </Icon>
                             <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                <FunctionName>showspecialModal</FunctionName>
                             </Action>
                          </Control>
                       </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                 </ExtensionPoint>
                 <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                    <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault2">
                       <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                       <Group id="msgReadGroup2">
                          <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                          <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                          <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton2">
                             <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                             <Supertip>
                                <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                                <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                             </Supertip>
                             <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                             </Icon>
                             <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                <FunctionName>showspecialModal</FunctionName>
                             </Action>
                          </Control>
                       </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                 </ExtensionPoint>
                 <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
              </DesktopFormFactor>
               <MobileFormFactor>
                  <FunctionFile resid="fnFile" />
                  <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
                     <Group id="mobileGroupID">
                        <Label resid="residAppName" />
                        <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="TaskPaneBtn">
                           <Label resid="residTaskPaneButtonName" />
                           <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                              <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="icon16" />
                           </Icon>
                           <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                              <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                           </Action>
                        </Control>
                     </Group>
                  </ExtensionPoint>
               </MobileFormFactor>
            </Host>
         </Hosts>
         <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
               <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/app-16.png" />
               <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/app-32.png" />
               <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/Images/app-80.png" />
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
               <bt:Url id="fnFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/functions.html" />
               <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/task-pane.html" />
            </bt:Urls>
           <bt:ShortStrings>
              <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Red Planet" />
              <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="Red Planet Tab" />
              <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="special Reply" />
              <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties" />
              <bt:String id="groupLabel2" DefaultValue="Red Planet2" />
              <bt:String id="customTabLabel2" DefaultValue="Red Planet Tab2" />
              <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel2" DefaultValue="special Reply2" />
              <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle2" DefaultValue="Get all properties2" />
               <bt:String id="residTaskPaneButtonName" DefaultValue="Mobile test" />
               <bt:String id="residAppName" DefaultValue="Mobile Testing" />
               <bt:String id="residTaskpaneUrl" DefaultValue="Mobile test2" />
           </bt:ShortStrings>
           <bt:LongStrings>
              <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Open up the special send dialog." />
              <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription2" DefaultValue="Open up the special send dialog." />
           </bt:LongStrings>
         </Resources>
      </VersionOverrides>
   </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 0):

MobileFormFactor can only be specified when the xsi:type attribute value for  VersionOverrides is VersionOverridesV1_1.

You can also refer [this](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/mobileformfactor) for more info

Comment: i have a nested VersionOverrides 1_1 with the mobile form factor. The link doesn't provide any extra clarity unfortunately

Comment: @matthewdaniel For clarity you should read and research documentation yourself. Try to be fair to ppl who is spending the time to help you, not just vote down and say it didn't work. Best regards.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov I have read the documentation unfortunately office-addins seems beta quality with various conflicting and ever changing documentation. Down voted due to MobileFormFactor already being wrapped in VersionOverridesV1_1 so answer is irrelevant

Comment: @matthewdaniel Of cause, it's all up to you.